# SumIf specific cells with merged rows

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula, sum

I have a spreadsheet where the first column (A) has merged cells, and column (D) has values. I do not want all of the values to be summed up. I want to exclude the first value. So in the example I uploaded there are the values 6,7,20 in the first merged cell group. I only want the sum of the 7 and 20.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjzrO.png)

[image]

Comment: Is the choice of values (negating the first one) subject to the value in coiumn A, B and/or C?

Comment: The values in column D are subject to the value in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an array formula in H5 (per supplied image),

```
  =SUM(IF(LOOKUP(ROW(A$2:A$100), ROW(A$2:A$100)/(A$2:A$100<>""),A$2:A$100)=G5, D$2:D$100))-INDEX(D:D, MATCH(G5, A:A, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much.